# New Line textbox

Tags: c#, html, textbox

I have a comment box that users can fill and saving the text in a MySQL database:

When a users fills text in my textbox with a backslash (`\n)` it shows in the text box without the new line.

For example, the user enters:

> Hi everyone!
>
> Me

The Textbox displays:

> Hi Everyone!Me

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to just use enter?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead of "`\n`" (or at least "`\r\n`", since this is what `Environment.NewLine` contains on non-Unix platforms anyway).

Also, make sure your [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx)'s [`MultiLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline.aspx) property is set to `true`.

```
myTextBox.MultiLine = true;
myTextBox.Text = "hi," + Environment.NewLine + "ALL";
```

Comment: the newline comment is only handy when setting text in code. So you should capture the keypresses and when the last command is \r\n then replace that with Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the [Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff.aspx) property?

```
textBox.Multiline = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : when extracting from database use this :

```
str_replace("\n",'<br />',$databasefield)
```

it`s working for me:)